# Regex: Why do empty strings get included (in a list of tuples) in re.findall()?

Tags: python, regex

According to the pattern match [here](https://regex101.com/r/nV3tW6/1), the matches are `213.239.250.131` and `014.10.26.06`.

Yet when I run the generated Python code and print out the value of `re.findall(p, test_str)`, I get:

```
[('', '', '213.239.250.131'), ('', '', '014.10.26.06')]
```

I could hack around the list and it tuples to get the values I'm looking for (the IP addresses), but (i) they might not always be in the same position in the tuples and (ii) I'd rather understand what's going on here so I can either tighten up the regex, or extract only IP addresses using Python's own `re` functionality.

Why do I get this list of tuples, why the apparent whitespace matches, and how do we ensure that only the IP addresses are returned?

Comment: Can't you put the match pattern here? Just for us, Please...

Comment: a) Post the damn regex, here, already. You can't incorporate-by-link to third-party site, which might go away in the future. b) The 'version 3' of your regex squelches the empty capture groups. So if you've already solved the problem using the answers here, please close the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Whenever you are using a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), it always returns a submatch, even if it is empty/null. You have 3 capturing groups, so you will always have them in the `findall` result.

In regex101.com, you can see these non-participating groups by turning them on in Options:

[image]

You may tighten up your regex by removing capturing groups:

```
(?:[a-z0-9]{1,4}:+){3,5}[a-z0-9]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

Or even `(?:[a-z0-9]{1,4}:+){3,5}[a-z0-9]{1,4}|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}`.

See [a regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nV3tW6/3)

**And since the regex pattern does not contain capturing groups, [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) will only return *matches*, not *capturing group contents*:**

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?:[a-z0-9]{1,4}:+){3,5}[a-z0-9]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')
test_str = "from mail.example.com (example.com. [213.239.250.131]) by\n mx.google.com with ESMTPS id xc4si15480310lbb.82.2014.10.26.06.16.58 for\n <alex@example.com> (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256\n bits=128/128); Sun, 26 Oct 2014 06:16:58 -0700 (PDT)"
print(re.findall(p, test_str))
```

Output of the [online Python demo](http://ideone.com/ml0wF7):

```
['213.239.250.131', '014.10.26.06']
```

Comment: Fantastic response, and thanks for making me aware of IDEONE.

Comment: Improved the answer to remove unnecessary code and complications.

Answer (score 1):

these are the capturing groups. 
if you do or queries it will return empty matches for the non matching expressions.

`(([a-z0-9]{1,4}:+){3,5}[a-z0-9]{1,4})|(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})`

the first or has 2 groups:
`(([a-z0-9]{1,4}:+){3,5}[a-z0-9]{1,4})`

and after the or there is the third:
`(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})`

to say it in a simple way each round bracket defines a capturing group which will show up if the value matches or not.