# Python regex - zero length matches using re.findall() v/s clean groups in regex101.com

Tags: python, regex

Why do I get zero length matches when using `re.findall()` and get none of those when evaluating the pattern on regex101:

```
text:
Relatie                    f. dsgfsdg\n 
Factuur                    26427432\n
Machtiging                 436346y435643yerhg\n
IncassantID                4ty43y643erhgerh\n
Onderwerp                  Uw factuur\n
Datum                      25 mei 2014\n
```

local (jupyter notebook):

```
re.findall('(Factuur)(\s+)(\d+)|(Datum)(\s+)(\d+\s+\w+\s+\d+)', content)
[('Factuur', '                    ', '2423828', '', '', ''),
 ('', '', '', 'Datum', '                      ', '25 mei 2014')]
```

regex101.com:

```
r"(Factuur)(\s+)(\d+)|(Datum)(\s+)(\d+\s+\w+\s+\d+)"
```

[image]

Comment: Format your question properly. The text you gave contains no long sequences of spaces and yet your matches do.

Comment: Because groups 4, 5, 6 are empty on Factuur line and groups 1, 2, 3 are empty on Datum line

Comment: The number of captures is equal to the number of capturing groups, and you have 6 in your pattern. Remove all empty items from the tuples, and that will yield the expected output.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Please update the question if you need a concrete solution. Until then, it is a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791936/regex-why-do-empty-strings-get-included-in-a-list-of-tuples-in-re-findall).

Comment: You could use `re.findall('^(Factuur|Datum)\s+(.+)$', content, re.M)`. It returns: `[('Factuur', '26427432'), ('Datum', '25 mei 2014')]`